# How to setup memcache, in XAMPP mac osx lion

Tags: php, macos, memcached, osx-lion, xampp

How to setup memcache in XAMPP, Mac OSX Lion. It was pretty simple in Leopard(using this link http://m-schmidt.eu/2010/03/30/develop-memcached-web-apps-with-xampp-under-mac-os-x/), but i installed fresh Lion and it seems that memcache is not installing.

I tried this one in https://gist.github.com/1301997 but no result!!

Can anyone suggest what to do.

Answer (score 6):

This is what helped me with Mac OS X Mountain Lion, XAMPP 1.7.3 (Standard way with "**pecl install**" doesn't work because it compiles **64 bit** extension while XAMPP is build in **32 bit** mode)

- I've got **memcached** server with **Xcode**
- I downloaded and installed **XAMPP Developer Package** from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html

(First sign you don't have this installed If you get this kind of warnings

```
    ...
    grep: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory 
    grep: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
    ...
```

)

- Instead of manually building **memcache extension** I've modified **PEAR installer** by adding line that configures build script with **32 bit** architecture flags:

```
    File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear/PEAR/Builder.php

    Was: 
    Line 323: // {{{ start of interactive part
    Line 324: $configure_command = "$dir/configure";
    Line 325: $configure_options = $pkg->getConfigureOptions();

    After modification:
    Line 323: // {{{ start of interactive part
    Line 324: $configure_command = "$dir/configure";
    Line 325: $configure_command .= " CFLAGS='-arch i386' APXSLDFLAGS='-arch i386' ";
    Line 326: $configure_options = $pkg->getConfigureOptions();
```

- Then from terminal I executed this:

```
    cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
    sudo ./pecl install memcache
```

- Restarted Apache server

And voila! I have php memcache extension working! Have a nice day! :)

Comment: I must agree with Jacob.  I just spent 2 hours aimlessly trying to make this work and FINALLY figured it out thanks to this post.  For those using XAMPP, this is the solution... nothing else works.

Answer (score 4):

First install Xampp developer tools. Then

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install memcache
```

Also not that apache server restart is needed.

Or you can check this for full guide.
http://wiki.cerb5.com/wiki/Setup:Development/XAMPP/Mac_OS_X